# Zorba: functions implemented from os (xquery-operators)?

Tags: xquery, zorba

I would like to use functions from the xquery-operators namespace (http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xquery-operators) in Zorba, specifically, op:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime.

However I get a static error: "op:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime": function with arity 2 not declared".  I had to declare the op namespace to get that far, so maybe Zorba uses a different prefix.  Or, maybe these functions aren't implemented.  I've had difficulty trying to search for answers to these questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec: Functions defined with the op prefix are described here to underpin the definitions of the operators in [XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0], [XQuery 1.0: An XML Query Language] and [XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 2.0]. These functions are not available directly to users, and there is no requirement that implementations should actually provide these functions. For this reason, no namespace is associated with the op prefix. For example, multiplication is generally associated with the * operator, but it is described as a function in this document.....

Can't you just use the + operator?

Comment: Yes, the + operator!  Zorba nicely returned an xs:dateTime when I added an xs:dateTimeDuration to an xs:dateTime.